# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes whilst using Teams through Google Chrome browser

Tags: 20.04, gnome, logs

I've only just installed Ubuntu 20.04 (around 5 days ago, so pretty clean install) and when I used MS Teams through the browser it was working ok to start with, then about 20 or 30 minutes into the meeting my whole OS GUI froze and I couldn't use anything.

As I was about to present in the meeting I did a hard reboot to try and get back in to the meeting, which I did, however it then later crashed again. This time I left it and eventually, after about 15 minutes, a "Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced an internal error" dialog showed up and the GUI was unfrozen.

I've attached the "All" logs and the "Important" logs, as well as a screen grab from the crash dialog.

The 2nd crash (which these logs relate to) happened at 13:54.

Any help isolating the problem will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Edit:
Crash report:
[image]

All logs:

```
14:05:32 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1425] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
14:05:27 systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
14:05:24 packagekitd: daemon quit
14:05:08 systemd: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
14:05:08 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1425] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
14:05:08 systemd: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
14:05:08 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1425] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=1421 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
14:04:56 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
14:04:56 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
14:04:56 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
14:04:56 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.144' (uid=1000 pid=9420 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-logs --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
14:04:14 systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
14:04:03 cat: [3118:7:0504/140403.396715:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:44 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
14:03:44 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
14:03:44 cat: [3118:16:0504/140344.418153:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:44 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
14:03:44 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.141' (uid=1000 pid=9420 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-logs --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
14:03:44 cat: [3118:7:0504/140344.338203:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:43 systemd: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
14:03:43 cat: [3118:6:0504/140343.833562:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:13 nautilus: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
14:03:13 cat: [3118:3:0504/140313.789132:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:13 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
14:03:13 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
14:03:13 cat: [3118:7:0504/140313.757584:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:13 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
14:03:13 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.139' (uid=1000 pid=9620 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
14:03:13 cat: [3118:3:0504/140313.691478:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:13 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1425] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
14:03:13 cat: [3118:19:0504/140313.372877:ERROR:h264_bitstream_parser.cc(206)] Streams with pred_weight_table unsupported.
14:03:13 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1425] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.135' (uid=1000 pid=6870 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
```

Important logs:

```
13:57:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2 [007f8db000 Xorg[1508]]
13:57:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2 [007f8db000 Xorg[1508]]
13:57:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:57:12 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:56:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2 [007f8db000 Xorg[1508]]
13:56:27 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:56:12 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:55:26 pulseaudio: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
13:55:26 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2 [007f8db000 Xorg[1508]]
13:55:26 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HUB/HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 2 [007f8db000 Xorg[1508]]
13:55:26 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:55:26 pulseaudio:   boundary     : 6206523236469964800
13:55:11 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:55:11 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1508]: failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1508]]
13:54:32 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 00000088a1003000 engine 1b [CE2] client 00 [HUB/VIP] reason 07 [WO_VIOLATION] on channel -1 [1a24ce00000 unknown]
13:54:32 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
13:31:22 pulseaudio: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
13:31:03 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
13:30:53 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0134.0006: No inputs registered, leaving
13:30:53 kernel: x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
```

Comment: I use Teams in Chrome and Ubuntu 20.04 and never had this problem. Have you tried installing the Teams Linux desktop app as a workaround?

Comment: I don't see any attached logs. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` (when running Teams and Chrome) and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `top`.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually added the logs now. I did some googling and found "assertion kref failed" to be to do with using the Nouveau drivers with my 4x display port nvidia gcard. I've switched to the nvidia drivers and hopefully that solves it...

Answer (score 1):

I am a terrible person to tell you this, but have you tried it into Microsoft Edge beta on Ubuntu. I've had a couple of run in with some users on Microsoft Teams on google Chrome on Windows OS and same issue occured. Although not in Microsoft Edge (chromium).

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-beta/microsoft-edge-beta_91.0.864.15-1_amd64.deb
```